# How to read event logs with folders?

Tags: c#, windows-8, system.diagnostics

I want to programmatically get the event log that appears in a folder in eventvwr.  This one is for Windows 8 Apps: Microsoft-Windows-AppHost/Admin.  I'm running as Admin.

This is not working:

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("Microsoft-Windows-AppHost/Admin");
```

This is not working either:

```
EventLogQuery queryMicrosoftWindowsAppHost = new EventLogQuery("Microsoft-Windows-AppHost/Admin", PathType.LogName);
_eventsMicrosoftWindowsAppHost = new List<EventRecordWrittenEventArgs>();
_eventLogWatcherMicrosoftWindowsAppHost = new EventLogWatcher(queryMicrosoftWindowsAppHost);
_eventLogWatcherMicrosoftWindowsAppHost.EventRecordWritten += (object sender, EventRecordWrittenEventArgs e) =>
{
    _eventsMicrosoftWindowsAppHost.Add(e);
};
_eventLogWatcherMicrosoftWindowsAppHost.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: are you trying to do this from a Windows Store app (which is likely going to work) or from a desktop app?  What does "not working" mean? exceptions?

Comment: I'm trying to query the event logs from OUTSIDE the Appx, with a regular old C# console app. I'm not getting any errors, just that the event log is not found.  Is the syntax for querying the event log correct?  i.e. "Microsoft-Windows-AppHost/Admin".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the event log using this code:

```
EventLogReader reader = new EventLogReader("Microsoft-Windows-AppHost/Admin");
var evt = reader.ReadEvent();
while (evt!= null)
{
    // Write the message to the console
    Console.WriteLine(evt.FormatDescription());
    evt = reader.ReadEvent();
}
```

If you want to attach your handler, your code is close, but you can simply pass the string into the watcher, instead of using the query object:

```
var watcher = new EventLogWatcher("Microsoft-Windows-AppHost/Admin");
watcher.EventRecordWritten += (object s, EventRecordWrittenEventArgs e1) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e1.EventRecord.FormatDescription());
    };
watcher.Enabled = true;
```